# Instalar Laravel 5.3 em servidor ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ubuntu, composer

Ao executar o comando `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` é instalado o Laravel 5.2. A minha máquina está instalada com php 5.5.9 mas no site está instalado o php 5.6.26. Porque é que não é instalado o laravel 5.3?

Comment: Também aconteceu isso comigo essa semana. Veja como está o `composer.json`.

Comment: '"name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"'

Comment: Preciso de alterar os dados no composer.json?

Comment: Só a versão do Lavarel.

Comment: Acredito que você deva configurar seu servidor para o php 5.6.26 de uma forma geral! e por isso da instalação! assim eu acredito que o php que você está chamando é o mais antigo.

Comment: @Gumball Ao fazer composer update ele diz que tenho a versão 5.5.9 do php e não a 5.6.26, mas no php info está 5.6.26

Comment: Eu instalei o 5.6.26 através do Plesk na opção de múltiplas instalações do php e no phpinfo está 5.6.26. Porque não reconhece?

Comment: É porque a instalação global PHP ou configurada no composer deve ser a 5.5, se não configurar o composer para usar a sua outra instalação ele não vai conseguir encontrar sozinho.

Answer (score 3):

Não está instalando porque a [Documentação do Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade) deixa bem claro:

> Laravel 5.3 requires PHP 5.6.4 or higher. HHVM is no longer officially supported as it does not contain the same language features as PHP 5.6+.

Ou seja, você precisa ter na sua máquina uma versão igual ou superior ao PHP 5.6.4 para que o Laravel 5.3 seja instalado.

## Atualização

Conversei com o AP no chat e resolvemos o problema. O problema era que o comando `php` estava reconhecendo a versão do PHP como `5.5.9`, mas na verdade, como ele instalou via `plesk`, era necessário rodar o `php` que estava na pasta do Plesk, que era `/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php`. Parece que Plesk é uma ferramenta para facilitar a instalação de múltiplas versões do PHP, por isso ele não afetou o PHP que estava instalado pelo `apt-get` do Linux.

Rodamos o comando abaixo para executar a instalação:

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

E assim, o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Eu instalei o 5.6.26 através do Plesk na opção de múltiplas instalações do php e no phpinfo está 5.6.26. Porque não reconhece?

Comment: Se estiver usando o Apache, provavelmente você teria que habilitar ele. Se não estiver usando apache, certifique-se que realmente está rodando a versão 5.6 >= do PHP. Rode `php -v`.

Comment: Quando executo 'php -v' ele diz que estou usando 5.5.9. Sendo assim é só habilitar o Apache? Como procedo para habilitar?

Comment: Não, você instalou PHP 5.6 na sua máquina? Certifique-se de que,  além do comando `php`, não exista um outro. Como `php5.6` por exemplo. Para rodar no apache precisa ter instalado. Caso não resolva o problema, você vai ter que detalhar mais sua pergunta, ou mesmo criar uma  nova, pois essa informação do Plesk não estava adicionada no corpo da pergunta até o momento que eu respondi.

Comment: Sim eu tenho instalado o php 5.5.9 para o ubuntu mas para o site em si tenho o 5.6.26, instalado através do Plesk. Peço desculpa mas não consigo compreender a parte de não existir outro comando.

Comment: Tá. Quero dizer o seguinte. Você está tentando instalar o Laravel 5.3 na sua máquina, certo? Só vai instalar se você atualizar seu php para 5.6. **Até aqui estamos entendidos**. Agora, sobre o outro comando, citei pois meu `Ubuntu`, além de rodar o comando `php`, tenho a opção de rodar `php5.6` ou `php7.0`. Para conferir isso basta digitar `php` na linha de comando e depois teclar `tab` para ver se vai aparecer alguma "completação".

Comment: Realmente não aparece 5.6, como devo proceder?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45981/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-costinha).